# Bound must be positive error when running automated tests

Tags: java, automation

When running a suite of inherited automated tests, I receive the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
at LinkGeneratorWww.getRandomPage(LinkGeneratorWww.java:166)
```

The code below seems to be the issue but I cannot figure out how to resolve it.

```
public static String getRandomPage() {

    List<String> pages = getAllPagesInDatabase();

    //get random page from the list
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(pages.size());

    return pages.get(randomNumber);
}
```

I've seen other posts that have had the same issue but would appreciate any assistance.
I tried resolving this by changing `pages.size()` to `pages.size()+1` but it started returning a different error `(Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0)`

Comment: It seems `pages.size()` is 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). -  Your method `getAllPagesInDatabase()` returns an empty list. The possible solution depends if that is an expected case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check size of the list before returning one of them. So if the list was empty you can return `null` or throw an `Exception` :

```
public static String getRandomPage() {

    List<String> pages = getAllPagesInDatabase();
    if(pages == null || pages.size() == 0)
        return null;

    //get random page from the list
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(pages.size());

    return pages.get(randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: This answer is good but note that you will need to look at all the callers of getRandomPage() and make sure that they are able to handle a null value -- they will probably need to check for it.